# How does FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK works?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm very confused about `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` in combination to `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. Isn't `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` supposed to clear TARGET task but not caller task?

Let's assume I have this navigation

```
A -> B -> C
```

Where `B` calls `C` with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`. How is that supposed to clear `A` and `B` from stack? I know that's happening because I tested it (If I click back on `C`, I leave the app), but I don't fully understand why... `A` and `B` are part of a different task that is not the task `C` will be created on.

**FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK**

> If set in an Intent passed to Context.startActivity(), this flag will cause **any existing task that would be associated with the activity** to be cleared before the activity is started.

Maybe text in bold above means that caller and target task are cleared. It's unclear to me what `associated` would be.

Comment: Why do you think A,B and C are in different tasks?

Comment: This link could be helpful: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/why-use-flagactivitycleartask-when-using-flagactivitynewtask-from-navigation-with-back-and-up-video

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK) will clear all existing task by starting the new activity in your case it's `C`.

I think you need [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) and this will clear only the top activity from stack in your case `B`.

You might be interesting with other flags, check [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

Answer (score 0):

`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` can only be used with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and it doesn't create a new task. All the activities in the current task are getting finished and the new activity(C in your case) becomes the root of the task.

`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` in your case will create a new task and make C the root of that task.

You can read more about how exactly `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` work [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK).